# Image Preprocessing in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

So i recently took a very deep dive into machine learning using keras and tensorflow. I have been working on a dataset for skin cancer detection, i have all the images in a separate folder, and together with it came two  separate csv files :hmnist_8_8_L( **has 64 columns which i guess is a 8 by 8 pixel representation**) and hmnist_8_8_RGB(**has 194 columns that i dont know how they got**).

My worry is that perhaps i didn't get a clear understanding of  how this two files were arrived at? how did the hmnist_8_8_RGB.csv get the 194 columns out of a single image?

Comment: We can only guess. You need to look at the dataset documentation or consult the authors. But a good guess (given that the filename is RGB) is that you have color images (8x8x3 = 192, I don't know where the other two columns come from).

Comment: hey @cheersmate sorry for not including https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/skin-cancer-mnist-ham10000#hmnist_8_8_RGB.csv) in my question. The real images are like 640 by 450 pixels, why 8 by 8? can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the data (https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/skin-cancer-mnist-ham10000#hmnist_8_8_RGB.csv) i see that the file contains 192 pixel columns and the label.
So the columns in your hmnist_8_8_RGB.csv  should be 193 and not 194.
Since the images used for this file are in RGB scale you have 8x8x3 =192 ( pixels x pixels x color channels). The last column is the label category.

Please pay attention that also in the file  hmnist_8_8_L the last column is dedicated to the label.

As marginal note, in future try to give more context in your question. Ad example a link to the dataset would have been appreciated

Comment: Thank you very much @Roberto , I appreciate your input very much thanks again. But , The real images are 640 by 450 pixels how comes we  have a 8 by 8 or 28 by 28 pixel arrays ?? The problem is that kaggle did not give out any clear description of the dataset.

Comment: Looking at the code (https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/dermatology-mnist-loading-and-processing) it seems that the images are resclaled to different scale sizes: 8x8, 28x28,... (see line 17 of the notebook).